# stripe-node timeout errors are unhandled for autopaging functions?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

Stripe's popular stripe-node library frequently times out when running autopaging functions.

```
stripe.charges.list().autoPagingEach(async charge => {
        await collectCharges(charge);
        if (charge === '') {
            return false;
        }
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('-Done retrieving charges-');
    });
```

Try catch blocks in our own code or in the provided node package don't help, despite being recommended by Stripe.

Stripe's code i the provided package, which stack trace points back to :

```
req.on('error', function(error) {
        if (self._shouldRetry(null, requestRetries)) {
          return retryRequest(makeRequest, apiVersion, headers, 
requestRetries);
        } else {
          return self._errorHandler(req, requestRetries, callback)(error);
        }
      }
      });
```

This is throwing the error:

```
(node:415) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An error occurred with 
our connection to Stripe.
    at Constructor._Error (/mnt/c/projects/accounts- 
page/node_modules/stripe/lib/Error.js:12:17)
     at Constructor (/mnt/c/projects/accounts- 
page/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:139:13)
     at new Constructor (/mnt/c/projects/accounts- 
page/node_modules/stripe/lib/utils.js:139:13)
     at /mnt/c/projects/accounts- 
page/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:218:9
     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/projects/accounts- 
page/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:427:67)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Stripe can't explain who 'our' refers to in : 'An error occurred with 
    our connection to Stripe.'

Is 'our' Stripe, or someone else?

Why does a timeout cause a hard failure, and how can we keep trying if Stripe fails to respond?

Comment: Does the error still occur if you reduce the limit on each individual call? Could you also post the code you're calling Stripe's functions from? For reference, the "our" here is referring to the client (your code running the lib).

Comment: Thanks @taintedzodiac - That makes sense. The error still occurs with a limit in place, but seems to be at around the 20,000 record mark - We've tried with limits of 5 - 50,000 records. (it fails at random points, as though there's some intermittent connection issue.) That however seems to be an issue in itself - We envisaged the point of autopaging was to break up the operation into lots of individual (limited) calls, to avoid this issue. Essentially, we just want to keep retrying indefinitely, as we're confident (we hope) that Stripe will always respond inside (at least) a 24 hour window.